# How can I run Diablo II on Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)?

Tags: macos, diablo-ii

I planned on buying a digital copy of *Diablo II* to prep my left click muscles for any potential beta access to *Diablo III* in the near future. Despite the requirements stating that *Diablo II* can run on "Mac OS X 10.3.9+", the installer gave me "You can't open the application installer because PowerPC applications are no longer supported."

I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.1 where access to PowerPC applications has been phased out (the compatibility layer Rosetta isn't installed in 10.7). Is there any other way I can play *Diablo II* on my computer?

Comment: I thought I saw a tip somewhere about how to reinstall Rosetta (very experementally) from a 10.6 disc into 10.7, but I think I actually got that confused with another tip on how to keep Xcode 3 tools in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Barring an update from Blizzard that seems, to be frank, incredibly unlikely, The only way to play *Diablo II* on your Mac is to run an older operating system. Either natively, such as Windows via Boot Camp, or simply having an install of 10.6 on another partition, or through virtualization software like VMWare or Parallels.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: Indeed. I'm dual-booting Windows 7 to play Diablo II myself.

Comment: Actually I'm so happy to hear this. I was threatening installing it tonite for some reminiscing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always run [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop?icid=1479) - I honestly doubt D2 would need any more horse power than what parallels offers :)

Comment: There's also [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) which is free and might work as well.

Answer (score -2):

Use [PlayOnMac](http://www.playonmac.com/en) — works great once you figure out how to use it.