# I heard that you can no longer play Diablo 2 on the current gen Macs, is this true?

Tags: macos, diablo-ii

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>    • [How can I run Diablo II on Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29850/how-can-i-run-diablo-ii-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion)
>    • [Will the version of Diablo 2 included with the Collectors Edition of Diablo 3 run on modern Mac OS X?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64962/will-the-version-of-diablo-2-included-with-the-collectors-edition-of-diablo-3-ru)

I heard that you can no longer play Diablo 2 on the current gen Macs, is this true?  The reason being the new macs are intel based.

Comment: Take a look at those links: [Will the version of Diablo 2 included with the Collectors Edition of Diablo 3 run on modern Mac OS X?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64962/will-the-version-of-diablo-2-included-with-the-collectors-edition-of-diablo-3-ru), [How can I run Diablo II on Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29850/how-can-i-run-diablo-ii-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion) **also** take a look in our [search](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=)

Comment: you can now!  they fixed it

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
As I read in comments above, the question has kind of been answered [there](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29850/how-can-i-run-diablo-ii-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion) and [there](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64962/will-the-version-of-diablo-2-included-with-the-collectors-edition-of-diablo-3-ru)

Should I delete my answer now?

**Original Answer:**

---

Well I don't think it has so much to do with the fact that new Macs are intel based, but that Diablo 2 only supports Mac up to Snow Leopard (as I see in the [requierements](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-ii-minimum-system-requirements) )

You can however install Diablo 2 on a Windows partition(via Bootcamp) on your Mac, which I would strongly recommend. Probably even a virtual machine on Mac would work, but I don't have a Mac, so I've never tested that.

A quick google search showed [this statement](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/playing-older-blizzard-titles-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion) by Blizzard on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the game client as of this moment does not support Lion (OS X 10.7). It would take little effort for Blizzard to enable their client to run in Lion environment, but I guess they have other priorities right now.

My recommendations to you would be to run the game in BootCamp. I do that with most game titles, even some with a mac ported version (as Team Fortress and Left4Dead.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (easily) play Diablo 2 on OSX Lion 10.7+, because Lion no longer supports Rosetta. Rosetta is a piece of software through which PowerPC code can be run on an Intel Macs.

Apple made the switch from PowerPC to Intel a couple of years back. Their reasoning was that the performance per watt of power was far superior to PowerPC in the long run.

OSX worked on both PowerPC and Intel up till Leopard. Snow Leopard could only run on Intel-based Macs, but could use Rosetta to run the older PowerPC apps on the newer OS.

Unfortunately for some, Apple has decided to no longer develop 'Rosetta' going forward, so Lion cannot run PowerPC apps.

There a bunch or method to run D2 on Lion (and above). Such as partitioning (Boot Camp, Use 10.6 [Snow Leopard] or later), [Wine](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1277412) ([Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/#cxmac)), or virtualization (Virtual Box, VMware etc).